# Angular typed reactive form via FormBuilder in strict mode

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms, formbuilder

I'm trying to follow [tutorial](https://blog.angular-university.io/angular-typed-forms/) (Angular 15), buit it doesn't work
https://gist.github.com/jhades/2d678f0140a013ec3d0b5eb2e450944c#file-01-ts

```
@Component({
  selector: 'login',
  templateUrl: './login.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./login.component.css']
})
export class LoginComponent {

   form = this.fb.group({
      email: ["", {
        validators: [Validators.required, Validators.email]
      }],
      password: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(8)]]
   });

  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {

  }

  login() {

  }
}
```

Throws

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'group')
```

It seems the FormBuilder doesn't instantiate. I've tried to do it the "usual" way https://gist.github.com/jhades/2d678f0140a013ec3d0b5eb2e450944c#file-02-ts which works (I have to do `form!: FormGroup` though), but it's explicitely stated not to use this way, because then you lose form typing.

Answer (score 1):

The code you posted seems to work just fine. [StackBlitz here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ab1t4u?file=src/app/input-clearable-example.ts)

Comment: Was about to post this - can't reproduce this issue!

Comment: Enable `ES2022` + `useDefineForClassFields` and you'll trigger this error

Comment: You learn something new every day! This is a good breakdown of it: https://angular.schule/blog/2022-11-use-define-for-class-fields

Comment: Seems you just need to enable `ES2022` and it defaults `useDefineForClassFields` to `true`
So I suppose there's no "future proof" solution to this, to keep the ease of FormBuilder and types, unless one wants to declare type for every form field himself (which kinda defeats purpose of using FormBuilder)

Answer (score 1):

You are likely to have in your `tsconfig.json` :

```
{
   target: "es2022",
   useDefineForClassFields: true
}
```

Disabling `useDefineForClassFields`  will solve your problem !

Comment: Well, yes, until Angular decides to make the flag true in the future.

Answer (score -1):

In your project, open tsconfig.json:

```
"strict": false,
```

This will help you resolve your issue.

Comment: I'm not going to turn off strict mode